# Are there any documents for Eigen/CXX11?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, eigen3

I would like to add a new Op to TensorFlow. I find that most Ops in TF are implemented using the tensor operations implemented in ``third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor'', which seems to be independent of the original Eigen library. Are there any documents for the new Eigen/CXX11 library?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [README](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/677c9f1577810e869f4f09881cabc3e503a810c1/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) describes how to use the Eigen Tensor module. For an overview, you can also refer to this [wiki page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support)

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: This link always points to the newest/current version of the [READMEs](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md) default branch. (The original link points to an old version)